# Use ASP.NET MVC validation with jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have simple ASP.NET MVC action like this :

```
public ActionResult Edit(EditPostViewModel data)
{

}
```

The `EditPostViewModel` have validation attributes like this :

```
[Display(Name = "...", Description = "...")]
[StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "...")]
[Required()]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

In the view I am using the following helpers :

```
 @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.EditPostViewModel.Title, true)

 @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.EditPostViewModel.Title, 
                        new { @class = "tb1", @Style = "width:400px;" })
```

If I do a submit on a form that this textbox is placed in a validation will be done first on client and then on service(`ModelState.IsValid`).

Now I got a couple of questions :

1. Can this be used with jQuery ajax submit instead? What I am doing is simply remove the form and on clicking the submit button a javascript will gather data and then run the `$.ajax`.
2. Will the server side `ModelState.IsValid` work?
3. How can I forward validation problem back to the client and present it as if Im using the build int validation(`@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`)?

Example of Ajax call :

```
function SendPost(actionPath) {
    $.ajax({
        url: actionPath,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:
        {
            Text: $('#EditPostViewModel_Text').val(),
            Title: $('#EditPostViewModel_Title').val() 
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Edit 1:

Included on page :

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice answer below. Here's a related question. The answer allows for client-side or server-side validation. I'm in love with the JQuery code they provide. (No, it wasn't my answer.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987752/jquery-post-and-unobtrusive-ajax-validation-not-working-mvc-4

Answer (score 160, accepted):

## Client Side

Using the `jQuery.validate` library should be pretty simple to set up.

Specify the following settings in your `Web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

When you build up your view, you would define things like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.EditPostViewModel.Title, true)
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.EditPostViewModel.Title, 
                                new { @class = "tb1", @Style = "width:400px;" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.EditPostViewModel.Title)
```

***NOTE:*** These need to be defined within a form element

Then you would need to include the following libraries:

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

This should be able to set you up for client side validation

### Resources

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic5.aspx

## Server Side

**NOTE:** This is only for additional server side validation on top of `jQuery.validation` library

Perhaps something like this could help:

```
[ValidateAjax]
public JsonResult Edit(EditPostViewModel data)
{
    //Save data
    return Json(new { Success = true } );
}
```

Where `ValidateAjax` is an attribute defined as:

```
public class ValidateAjaxAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return;

        var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errorModel = 
                    from x in modelState.Keys
                    where modelState[x].Errors.Count > 0
                    select new
                           {
                               key = x,
                               errors = modelState[x].Errors.
                                                      Select(y => y.ErrorMessage).
                                                      ToArray()
                           };
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
                                       {
                                           Data = errorModel
                                       };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 
                                                  (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is return a JSON object specifying all of your model errors.

Example response would be

```
[{
    "key":"Name",
    "errors":["The Name field is required."]
},
{
    "key":"Description",
    "errors":["The Description field is required."]
}]
```

This would be returned to your error handling callback of the `$.ajax` call

You can loop through the returned data to set the error messages as needed based on the Keys returned (I think something like `$('input[name="' + err.key + '"]')` would find your input element

Comment: Great answer, especially with the awesome ValidateAjaxAttribute! Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got so many votes. It doesn't answer question 1: how to do client validation when posting with $.ajax? I think @Shyju answer helps with that.

Comment: @Valentin - my answer does help though because the data is validated server side as well. The validation plugins should enable dynamic validation as the form is filled out, and when the form is submitted (however the OP wants to do that), the server will provide final validation, which is preferable anyways since client side validation can be bypassed.

Comment: I utilise jQuery's validation message spans by looping through the errors returned and inserting the error message into the correct span: `for (var i = 0; i < modelStateErrors.length; i++) {

                    $('span[data-valmsg-for="' + modelStateErrors[i].key + '"]').text(modelStateErrors[i].errors[0]);

                }`

Comment: This answer is great! But I still think the ASP.NET MVC framework should provide a built-in way of doing that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For those who are trying to trigger the validation for dynamically loaded form, please add following line when the content is loaded.<pre><code>$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#yourdynamicallyloadedform'));</code></pre>

Answer (score 42):

What you should do is to serialize your form data and send it to the controller action. ASP.NET MVC will bind the form data to the `EditPostViewModel` object( your action method parameter), using MVC model binding feature.

You can validate your form at client side and if everything is fine, send the data to server. The [`valid()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) method will come in handy.

```
$(function () {

    $("#yourSubmitButtonID").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var _this = $(this);
        var _form = _this.closest("form");

        var isvalid = _form .valid();  // Tells whether the form is valid

        if (isvalid)
        {           
           $.post(_form.attr("action"), _form.serialize(), function (data) {
              //check the result and do whatever you want
           })
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this $("form#" + formId).validate() but it says that the form(that is found) do not have a validate()?

Comment: See Edit1 where I show that the validate script is included on the webpage. I also see that the validation is running when using a regular input type submit button.

Comment: I found the problem(removed Scripts.Render from masterpage). But still have problems to send back ModelState validation errors to the client? How am I supose to thandle that? For example if the user is not loggedin anymore( ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "validation text").

Comment: you need to include the jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive js files in your page. IS your HTML inputs have the attribute which validation plugins look for ?

Comment: I have added the 3 scripts that I am including on the page and the validate method do work now. The problem is how to handle return data from the service? Do I have to change the action from ActionResult to JsonResult? How do I forward the ModelState validation information from the action to the client form withint the $.post?

Comment: Ivy : Your return type (ActionResult) is a base class of JsonResult. so it can return JSON data. What you should do is, If it is an ajax call (check Request.IsAjax), get the validation errors and build a JSON and send it back to client. Check the json in the callback method of $.post and show the error messages.

Comment: I don't know if jquery.validation has this function in 2012 but now you can just use `$("form").valid()` which returns a boolean to check whether form is valid.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a rather simple solution:

In the controller we return our errors like this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here's some of the client script:

```
function displayValidationErrors(errors)
{
    var $ul = $('div.validation-summary-valid.text-danger > ul');

    $ul.empty();
    $.each(errors, function (idx, errorMessage) {
        $ul.append('<li>' + errorMessage + '</li>');
    });
}
```

That's how we handle it via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        var isSuccessful = (data['success']);

        if (isSuccessful) {
            $('#partial-container-steps').html(data['view']);
            initializePage();
        }
        else {
            var errors = data['errors'];

            displayValidationErrors(errors);
        }
    }
});
```

Also, I render partial views via ajax in the following way:

```
var view = this.RenderRazorViewToString(partialUrl, viewModel);
        return Json(new { success = true, view }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

RenderRazorViewToString method:

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                     viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                         ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your "GetModelStateErrors" can be simplified completely by converting it to a way simpler single-line statement: **return ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList();**

Comment: Why not simply return a `PartialView` to render to Ajax?

Answer (score 5):

Added some more logic to solution provided by @Andrew Burgess. Here is the full solution:

Created a action filter to get errors for ajax request:

```
public class ValidateAjaxAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return;

            var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
            if (!modelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errorModel =
                        from x in modelState.Keys
                        where modelState[x].Errors.Count > 0
                        select new
                        {
                            key = x,
                            errors = modelState[x].Errors.
                                                          Select(y => y.ErrorMessage).
                                                          ToArray()
                        };
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = errorModel
                };
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode =
                                                      (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            }
        }
    }
```

Added the filter to my controller method as:

```
[HttpPost]
// this line is important
[ValidateAjax]
public ActionResult AddUpdateData(MyModel model)
{
    return Json(new { status = (result == 1 ? true : false), message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Added a common script for jquery validation:

```
function onAjaxFormError(data) {
    var form = this;
    var errorResponse = data.responseJSON;
    $.each(errorResponse, function (index, value) {
        // Element highlight
        var element = $(form).find('#' + value.key);
        element = element[0];
        highLightError(element, 'input-validation-error');

        // Error message
        var validationMessageElement = $('span[data-valmsg-for="' + value.key + '"]');
        validationMessageElement.removeClass('field-validation-valid');
        validationMessageElement.addClass('field-validation-error');
        validationMessageElement.text(value.errors[0]);
    });
}

$.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: [],
            highlight: highLightError,
            unhighlight: unhighlightError
        });

var highLightError = function(element, errorClass) {
    element = $(element);
    element.addClass(errorClass);
}

var unhighLightError = function(element, errorClass) {
    element = $(element);
    element.removeClass(errorClass);
}
```

Finally added the error javascript method to my Ajax Begin form:

```
@model My.Model.MyModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddUpdateData", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnFailure="onAjaxFormError" }))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

(**Edit:** Considering that you're waiting for a response `json` with `dataType: 'json'`)

.NET

```
public JsonResult Edit(EditPostViewModel data)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
       // Save  
       return Json(new { Ok = true } );
    }

    return Json(new { Ok = false } );
}
```

JS:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.Ok) {
      alert('success');
    }
    else {
      alert('problem');
    }
},
```

If you need I can also explain how to do it by returning a error 500, and get the error in the event error (ajax). But in your case this may be an option

Comment: I know how to do a regular Jason request, this will however not help me with validation of the diffrent properties or even use the built in   ASP.NET MVC Validation that I asked for. I could probably build a complexed Jason object to explain the validation errors for every propertie but this will be alot of work and I am hoping that you can reuse the built in functionality of ASP.NET MVC validation for this?

Comment: 1 - How to run your function "SendPost"?, And 2 - your valid data on the client?

Comment: Pleas explain? Dont get your last post?