# How to JSON Serialize the MVC ModelState object for jQuery Validation consumption?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I'm unable to figure out the correct JSON object I need to pass into jQuery validation's showErrors() method. So on the client I have JavaScript:

```
  var validator = $("form").validate();
  validator.showErrors(modelstate_json);
```

And server-side extracting ModelState errors into JSON is easily done

```
var errors = (from e in ModelState where e.Value.Errors.Count > 0 select e)
ToDictionary(x => 
 x.Key, 
 x => x.Value.Errors
.Select(y => y.ErrorMessage)
.Concat(x.Value.Errors.Where(y => y.Exception != null)
.Select(y => y.Exception.Message)));

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors);
```

Which gives me something like

```
'{"Name": "Max 30 characters"}'
```

But passing this fragment to showErrors() does not trigger validation and display the message.

If I know the correct JSON to feed showErros() then I am hoping I can reverse engineer my serialization routine.

Thanks

Comment: This is backwards... you don't pass messages ***into*** `showErrors()`.  The error messages come ***from*** `showErrors()`.   The jQuery Validation plugin automatically triggers errors based on the user's data input and the two arguments for `showErrors()` come from the plugin itself.  [See documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Comment: I think you are for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14106135/894273)