# Unable to call MVC4 client side validation while using jquery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-validation

In my MVC view screen, on click of button, i do ajax call through `$.ajax` and it able to call controller's action method and return the reponse into success event.
controller action method's return type is `JsonResult` and returning `Json(object,AllowGEt)`
I have included jquery file and validation file in `_layout` file.

Problem: 
Problem is unable to fire validation on client side.

I have already included - `Required` annotaion and error message annotation on model object.

Please guide me what is wrong. 
(it was working fine while doing validation inside `BeginForm` and button as `Submit` button and call to action method having return type as `ActionResult` but, no ajax call.)

Modified to include code:

### On `View` on button click event :

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#btnJsonSubmit").click(function () {
      var f = JSON.stringify(
           { 'IDValue': objIDValue };
     $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cPreferences/InsertPreference',
        data: f,
        success: function () {
            alert('Record saved successfully.');
            $('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert('f');
            //console.log('error!!');
        }
        });
     });
   </script>
```

### On Controller's actio method:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult InsertPreference(string IDValue)
    {

       ///code to call services
      return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

### View Model object

View MOdel

```
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    namespace ViewModel
   {
     public class CampusProgramPreferencesViewModel
     {
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selection is required")]
     public IList<LookupItem> DataList { get; set; }
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preference is required")]

    public string Preference { get; set; }
    }
     }


  Layout_cshtml

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"   type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"   type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Please add yor view and action code in question

Comment: Please find updated question with detail code.

Comment: I test Your code.it's correct and worked.check your browser console for java script errors

Answer (score 0):

Please Make sure that you have included the following:

1)  Web Config changes:

**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

**

2)  Sequence of the script files i.e:

**

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

**

Further more you can refer the:
[Use ASP.NET MVC validation with jquery ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005773/use-asp-net-mvc-validation-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: My controller's action is `JSONRESULT`. Updated question with details, please guide,its not working. web.config already contains both lines.

Comment: Please use
Ajax.Begin form, as it seems that a form tag is not getting rendered on your page, b'coz MVC validation may work if you wrap the page objects in the form tag.